# Prohibit CSS table to be wider than outer container

Tags: html, css

I need to make three column header. Left and right columns should use all space they need and central should use all left space.

I decided to use CSS tables for this (because I need to support IE8). And it works fine when there is not much content in central column:

```css
.outercontainer {
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left">
         Left content
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        Center content
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        Right content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when there is much content, inner table becomes wider than outer container:

```css
.outercontainer {
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left">
         Left content
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        Center content is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        Right content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I prohibit overflowing outer container and force table not to become wider?

Comment: you have nowrap declared, so how do you imagine the content will fit?

Comment: Rather than using `display:table` for non-tabular data, you're probably much better using proper [CSS centering](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/299/centering#t=20170418194459491508) techniques and typing your class-names correctly: `.contaner` should be `.container`.

Comment: Edited my post. Removed `table-layout: fixed` and fixed `contaner` typo.

Comment: table-layout has its purpose here, best would be to use display:flex, display:grid is still too young to be a reliable option at this time

Answer (score 2):

Spell "container" correctly in your CSS and remove "width: 100%" from the center css

```css
.outercontainer {
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left">
         Left content
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        Center content is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        Right content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem in this case is left and right columns use more space than they need.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're really looking for is using flex. You say you want the left and right to use as much as they can, and have the middle one take up the remaining width? That's easy in flex. You can view this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wv3ck9ax/1/

```
.outercontainer {
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.left {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.center {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.right {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` would do perfectlythe job here:

```css
.outercontainer {
  width: 500px;
}

.container {}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.center {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left">
        Left content
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        Center content is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        Right content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

display:grid will someday

```css
.outercontainer {
  width: 500px;
}

.container {}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.left {
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.center {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left">
        Left content
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        Center content is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long is very long
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        Right content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```